# Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0022f5f8

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm trying to execute the code that's referred in http://ipwithopencv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ThinPlateSpline/ThinPlateSpline/ in Visual Studio 2010 but I always have this exception:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0022f5f8..
 kernelbase.dll!_RaiseException@16() + 0x54 BYTES
```

Here is the main programme :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "CThinPlateSpline.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    // load a nice picture

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg");

    // generate some generic points
    // usually you would use a interest point detector such as SURF or SIFT
    std::vector<cv::Point> iP, iiP;

    // push some points into the vector for the source image
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(50,50));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(400,50));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(50,400));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(400,400));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(256,256));
    iP.push_back(cv::Point(150,256));

    // push some point into the vector for the dst image
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(70,70));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(430,60));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(60,410));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(430,420));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(220,280));
    iiP.push_back(cv::Point(180,240));

    // create thin plate spline object and put the vectors into the constructor
    CThinPlateSpline tps(iP,iiP);


    // warp the image to dst
    Mat dst;
    tps.warpImage(img,dst,0.01,INTER_CUBIC,BACK_WARP);


    // show images
    cv::imshow("original",img);
    cv::imshow("distorted",dst);
    //cv::waitKey(0);
    //Sleep(5);
    cv::waitKey(5000); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that this compiles fine..? I just tried it out on my system and it worked without any problems. Are you using CMake to generate the project files..?

Comment: Is your Image File in the correct directory?

Comment: hey scap3y, No im not using cMake to generate the project files can u please give me a link to know how to use this software

Comment: yes my Image is the correct directory Mailerdom :(